# can you create a class containing an array of another class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class, xcode4

I'm attempting to prototype some things using XCode4 but I'm very new to ObjectiveC. Here's the issue.  In Java I would use something like this to define an object I want to use:

```
public class Event(){
String EventID;
String EventName;
ArrayList<EventTag> Tags;

}
```

So "EventTag" is another class and an Event can have one or more EventTags. This way my object has everything I need when I reference it. Is there an equivalent way to do this in Objective C?  Or is there are better way to what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Objective-c equivalent class declaration would look:

```
@interface Event:NSObject{
   NSString *eventID;
   NSString *eventName;
   NSMutableArray *tags;
}
```

Note that in objective-c code style instance variable names should start with lower-case letter. Also if you're not interested in any specific order of tags you may want to use `NSMutableSet` instead of array.

Also check [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) section in Objective-C reference to see the obj-c way of creating accessor methods to instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

You'd just use an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray` if you want to add/remove elements from the array). In Objective-C with Foundation (i.e. the `NS` family of classes) there's no way to have a container and specify that it only contains a certain type. All containers hold any object (i.e. something of type `id`).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you'd have a list that can only support `EventTag` objects and the compiler would create a warning/error if you would try to add something else. Objective-C does not support that, there are only "untyped" arrays (`NSArray` for static arrays and `NSMutableArray` for arrays that you can change) that can hold *any* Objective-C object. If you need a typed one you would need to create a wrapper class.